# LuaLaTeX invisible unicode characters

Tags: luatex, unicode

I have a minimal document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
this is λ lambda
\end{document}
```

When building with latex, is gives the error

```
Package inputenc: Unicode character λ (U+03BB)
(inputenc)    not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and when building with lualatex, it outputs:

[image: lambda]

(the unicode λ character is invisible)

How to make the λ visible?

Comment: Do you intend to use `λ` in text mode or in math mode?

Comment: Do you load the `fontspec` and/or `unicode-math` packages? Which text and math fonts do employ?

Comment: I intend to use unicode in text, math, and lstlisting. In only load what shown.

Comment: you will have a missing glyph warning in the log for luatex telling you that latin modern does not have a lambda. You need to choose a font via fontspec that includes greek.

Comment: Add `\tracinglostchars=2` so that the warning (it will say something like: `Missing character: There is no λ (U+03BB) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!`) shows up in the terminal and not just in the log file. Unfortunately, this is not the default (though IMO it should be).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not enough to provide utf8-encoded *input*. You also need to select text and math fonts that possess the glyphs you wish to typeset.

As the following screenshot reveals, `Latin Modern Roman` (the default system serif **text** font) doesn't feature a `λ` glyph, but `Latin Modern Math` does -- in both a slanted and in an upright shape. `Stix Two`, in contrast, possesses a `λ` glyph in both text and math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads 'fontspec' automatically
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
Latin Modern text and math font
this is λ lambda
this is $λ$ $\symup{λ}$ lambda

\bigskip
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
Stix Two text and math font
this is λ lambda
this is $λ$ $\symup{λ}$ lambda
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer since it allows to render the characters, but they are messed around in listings as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573244/strange-unicode-behavior-in-listings

Answer (score 6):

You need to load both a font and an encoding that supports Greek.  In LuaLaTeX, that’s Unicode, and you can automatically switch to your Greek language and font whenever you start typing in Greek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import=el, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}

\babelfont{rm}[ Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}[ Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbering

\begin{document}
This is λ lambda.

And \(λ\) in math mode.
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Book Sample]

You can define different fonts for `\babelfont[greek]{rm}`, and Babel will switch to them when you start typing in Greek in text mode.  It will use the symbols from your Unicode math font in math mode.  You can instead load Polyglossia if you prefer it to Babel.

My advice is to use LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math` when you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts when you have to.  Tn PDFTeX, the 8-bit font encoding you want is called LGR, and you also want `alphabeta` to enable Greek letters in both text and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbering

\begin{document}
This is λ lambda.

And \(λ\) in math mode.
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Roman sample]

If your main font does not come in LGR, you can declare a font substitution with `substitutefont`.

You were getting the error you did because PDFTeX only understands Unicode characters that you’ve set up, and the LaTeX kernel only sets up characters that are in one of the font encodings you’ve loaded.

If you check your `.log` file from your original LuaLaTeX MWE, you’ll see a warning message buried in the middle of it, saying that there was no λ glyph in the current font.  Other than that, TeX silently ignores the error.  This is terrible design, but apparently we’re stuck with it for the sake of backward compatibility.  The command `\tracinglostchars=2` will at least display the warning on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Mico's answer is correct but he doesn't give an example font to use which has Greek letters so I wanted to add the font GFS Artemisia by the Greek Font Society works well. The following should work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads 'fontspec' automatically
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}

\begin{document}
this is λ lambda
\end{document}
```