# strange unicode behavior in listings

Tags: listings, luatex, unicode

I have the minimal document here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont{Stix}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

\begin{document}
this is λ lambda
$$\int_0^\infty λ\lambda$$
\begin{lstlisting}
# some random pseudocode using unicode
def function(λ): 
    αδ = βθ

def function( λ): 
    pass
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

producing with lualatex:

[image]

Look at how the unicode characters are rendered in the listing, but not in the right place.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to add manually all the Unicode characters you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}

\makeatletter % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320345
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^20ac^^^^0153^^^^0152%
  ^^^^03b1% alpha
  ^^^^03b2% beta
  ^^^^03b4% delta
  ^^^^03bb% lambda
  ^^^^03b8% theta  
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}


\begin{document}
this is λ lambda
\[\int_0^\infty λ\lambda\]
\begin{lstlisting}
# some random pseudocode using unicode
def function(λ): 
    αδ = βθ

def function(λ): 
    pass
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use the `minted` package (compile with `--shell-escape`). Note that I changed the fonts because I don't have STIX or Fira Mono.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{minted}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
this is λ lambda
$$\int_0^\infty λ\lambda$$
\begin{minted}{python}
# some random pseudocode using unicode
def function(λ): 
    αδ = βθ

def function( λ): 
    pass
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not answer the question which was about listings. It works well with minted, even the unicode characters appear with a red rectangle around.

Comment: @HugoTrentesaux I agree that it does not answer the question as asked, but it may be a useful alternative (for you and/or for future visitors of the site). As you can see I don't have the red rectangles in my output (and indeed this is valid Python code).

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343494/minted-red-box-around-greek-characters could be useful to address the red rectangles, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14166/red-box-drawn-around-question-mark-operator-in-minted-erlang-code.

Comment: I upvoted this answer since it can be useful for other people but in my case I do not want to migrate my whole document to minted, that's why I trying to fix it using listings.