# Lualatex unicode input of greek symbols

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, greek

I am looking to input greek characters directly in the tex file. I could do this with pdflatex, but I cannot find a way to do this in lualatex. I really don't want to type `\greek{greeksymbol}` for every greek symbol that I have to insert, since some of my references will also have greek symbols, and I will have to go and change all of those as well.

MWE of my current solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec} % lualatex only
\usepackage{unicode-math} % lualatex only
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{$\mathbfup{#1}$}

\begin{document}

Protein secondary structure includes \greek{α}-helices and \greek{β}-sheets.

\end{document}
```

which outputs this[image]

where as in an ideal world all I would have to type is

```
% whatever packages are needed to accomplish this
\begin{document}

Protein secondary structure includes α-helices and β-sheets.

\end{document}
```

and it would display the same thing. Does anyone have any solutions? It needs to be within lualatex because I am using OTF fonts.

EDIT:

So here is a MWE where I can type it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec} % lualatex only
\usepackage{unicode-math} % lualatex only
\usepackage[american,greek]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=el, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

Protein secondary structure includes α-helices and β-sheets.

\end{document}
```

Awesome. Is there a way for it to be automatically boldended? I would like to have all greek symbols in bold.

Comment: You should take a look at this question: [LuaLaTeX invisible unicode characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573214/lualatex-invisible-unicode-characters)

Comment: I thought there would be a way to do this without changing my font, since that requires ```\setmainfont{Stix Two Math}``` while I really would like to keep using lmr for my main font. I don't know why this is so difficult on lualatex, but on pdflatex this was really straight forward.

Comment: @jfang5 There were two answers to the question Enevevet linked, one of them shows how to integrate Greek without changing the main font.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a way to then for it to automatically be boldened? ```\textbf{greeksymbol} ``` didn't seem to have an effect, while my MWE obviously does.

Comment: why did you change the text font to latin modern math? Math fonts typically don't have a bold version. Use a proper text font with greek symbols, e.g. `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{fontsetup}
\begin{document}
    Protein secondary structure includes α-helices and β-sheets. \par
    Protein secondary structure includes \textbf{α}-helices and \textbf{β}-sheets.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I saw this a while ago but I mistook fontsetup for fontspec, and I thought there was a way to do it with fontspec. Thanks!